# multithreaded search of prime numbers

Tags: c, multithreading, cpu-cores

I have this code that is counting the number of prime numbers below an input number:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Math.h>

int is_prime(long num)
{
    int k = 1, a = 0, b = 0;
    long sr;
    switch(num)
        {
        case 1: return 0;
        case 2: return 1;
        case 3: return 1;
        case 4: return 0;
        case 5: return 1;
        case 6: return 0;
        case 7: return 1;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0) return 0;
    if (num % 3 == 0) return 0;
    sr = (int) sqrt(num);
    while (b < sr) {
        a = (6 * k) - 1;
        b = (6 * k) + 1;
        if (num % a == 0)
            return 0;
        if (num % b == 0)
            return 0;
        k += 1;
    }
    return 1;
}

void main()
{
    int j;
    long num=0;
    printf("insert your number to check for prime numbers\n");
    scanf("%ld",&num);
    for (j = 0; j<num; j++){
        if (is_prime(j))
            printf("%d is a prime\n", j);
    }
}
```

Part of a challenge - someone asked me if I can accelerate my calculation by multi-core processing, and I answered that yes. For example, if I want to check for primes below 100, Ill use thread number one for calculating 2-50 and thread number two for calculating 51-99.

He said that I'll have to think it over because there is a basic fault in running 2-50 on the 1st core, and 51-99 on the 2nd core for x equal 100.

Does anybody know if he is right? And if so, what is the proper way of doing it for multi-core architecture?

Answer (score 4):

The work to compute is_prime(n+k) is, generally speaking, larger than the amount of work to compute is_prime(n).   You're giving all of the easiest work to one core, and all of the hardest work to the other, meaning you're unlikely to come anywhere near the ideal 2X speed up you could get if you divided it more evenly (e.g. naively, even numbers on one, and odd on the other, so that the amount of work is divided roughly evenly.  Except don't do that; I hope you  catch the **obvious** flaw, there :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was something along these lines:

```
   void threadfunction()
   {
       for(;;)
       {
          number = pick_next_number();   // Should be atomic. 
          if (number > maxnumber)
              return;
          if (is_prime(number))
              printf("%d\n", number);
       }
   }
```

Then basically just run as many of these as you need.

A couple of problems is that `printf` isn't threadsafe, and it will probably output the numbers out of order even if `printf` was threadsafe. So, you need to fix those problems - for example by using an atomic store in an array, and simply print them at the end of the execution.

Answer (score 0):

you could get a very close approximation of the number of primes less than N by using the prime number theorem which is π(x)~x/ln(x)

π(x) is the prime counting function unrelated to the pi constant.